# Input files from ExpressionEngine?

Tags: input, expressionengine

Is there a way to reference uploaded files using EE's Input class? I know it has a "post" method to get post variables, but what about files?

Answer (score 1):

Not in the input class, you can just use $_FILES.

You may want to have a look at the Upload class though. For a good overview of how it works, you can check out the function _upload_file() in the Filemanager library file within your EE directory.  A primer:

```
    $this->EE->load->library('upload');
    $this->EE->upload->initialize($config);

    if ( ! $this->EE->upload->do_upload($field_name))
    {
        return $this->_upload_error(
            $this->EE->upload->display_errors()
        );
    }

    $file = $this->EE->upload->data();
```

The `$config` array contains the options for the upload, which you can review in the [CodeIgniter docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).